# how to create previous and next button done button panel on top of keyboard and arrows for < > for ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

User needs to fill form data on screen and it is a long one.
For these purpose i need to add panel on top of keyboard
How can i present it in via code and different set of buttons for ios 7

```
UIToolbar * keyboardToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];

keyboardToolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
[keyboardToolBar setItems: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Previous" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(previousTextField)],
                            [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Next" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(nextTextField)],
                            [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                            [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(resignKeyboard)],
                            nil]];

textField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolBar;
```

Comment: and what exactly is the problem with your code?

Comment: @MatthiasBauch - how can i change icons when ios 7 comes up and can i manage different screen sizes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this control

https://github.com/simonbs/BSKeyboardControls

It is currently supporting ios 5+ onwards
It presents different UI for ios 7 as well

Comment: Its so easy to implement and good api - i am just testing it - will let you know if any problems with that